# Getting Google Chart into Jquery Dialog window (using AJAX)

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui-dialog, visualization, google-visualization

I have a page; let's call it somepage.phtml with originally PHP values encoded in json and added as values to drawVisualization function (the data is there, it's fine) which is initialized also on this page.

Then this which should contain the chart.

```
<div  id="visualization" style="width: 500px; height: 400px; display:block"></div>
```

Then I have central javascript file, containing functions for my application written using Jquery. All required scripts are initialized, for Jquery, gVis. api. everything.

I want to click on some link on the mainpage and make Jquery Dialog appear with the Google Chart in it loaded from the page somepage.phtml.

I tried to load images, text, other javascript, php vaules, everything works but not this graph.

My function in Jquery is like this:

```
$('#shop-offers td.offer-graph a').click(function() {       
    var url = $(this).attr("href");     
    $.get(url, function(data) {
         $('<div></div>').html(data).dialog({
            modal: true,                
            minHeight: 350,
            minWidth: 550                       
                });
        });
    return false;
});
```

After first click, instead of triggering Dialog, nothing happens.

After second click, the blank page is loaded, getting continuously data from Google.

I also tried this with graph from google playground with the same effect - didn't work.

For the example chart, in this moment Firebug outputs in scripts:

```
function drawVisualization() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["Name", "Height", "Smokes"],["Tong  Ning mu", 174, true], ["Huang Ang fa", 523, false], ["Teng nu", 86, true]]);
(new Google.visualization.ImageLineChart(document.getElementById("visualization"))).draw(data, null);
}

function drawVisualization() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["Name", "Height", "Smokes"], ["Tong Ning mu", 174, true], ["Huang Ang fa", 523, false], ["Teng nu", 86, true]]);
(new google.visualization.ImageLineChart(document.getElementById("visualization"))).draw(data, null);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```